# How to remove backslash from htmlString using swift program?

Tags: swift3

https://d30er1j1ecun0i.cloudfront.net/check-square.png\" alt=\"check_box\" style=\"width: 100%;display: block;\"/>National Rankinghttps://d30er1j1ecun0i.cloudfront.net/check-square.png\" alt=\"check_box\" style=\"width: 100%;display: block;\"/>Access to Resource Guide - Weekly Training Guide - Nutrition - Recruitinghttps://d30er1j1ecun0i.cloudfront.net/check-square.png\" alt=\"check_box\" style=\"width: 100%;display: block;\"/>Up-to-date Expanded Report - College Ranking - National Ranking in each Testhttps://d30er1j1ecun0i.cloudfront.net/check-square.png\" alt=\"check_box\" style=\"width: 100%;display: block;\"/>Live Event Leaderboardhttps://d30er1j1ecun0i.cloudfront.net/check-square.png\" alt=\"check_box\" style=\"width: 100%;display: block;\"/>VIP access to additional camps and combines

Comment: There's no backslash. They're virtual: inserted by the system when printing for debugging. You cannot remove something that's not there.

Answer (score 0):

```
let htmlString = "https://d30er1j1ecun0i.cloudfront.net/check-square.png\" alt=\"check_box\" style=\"width: 100%;display: block;\"/>National Rankinghttps://d30er1j1ecun0i.cloudfront.net/check-square.png\" alt=\"check_box\" style=\"width: 100%;display: block;\"/>Access to Resource Guide - Weekly Training Guide - Nutrition - Recruitinghttps://d30er1j1ecun0i.cloudfront.net/check-square.png\" alt=\"check_box\" style=\"width: 100%;display: block;\"/>Up-to-date Expanded Report - College Ranking - National Ranking in each Testhttps://d30er1j1ecun0i.cloudfront.net/check-square.png\" alt=\"check_box\" style=\"width: 100%;display: block;\"/>Live Event Leaderboardhttps://d30er1j1ecun0i.cloudfront.net/check-square.png\" alt=\"check_box\" style=\"width: 100%;display: block;\"/>VIP access to additional camps and combines"

htmlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
print(htmlString)
```

Then the result should not consist any backslash anymore